# Jquery onblur not working second time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have build a jQuery PHP based instant search, I have used some fading effect along with onblur event, everything is working fine except when clicking anywhere in body for first time results disappear, but again if hover over to input field to bring result and then clicking in body results do not disappers,
i.e onblur does not work second time.

Please see my code for better understanding and suggest any possible way to do this.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#search-input').keyup(function(){
        var keyword=$(this).val();
        $.get('../search/instant-search.php', {keyword: keyword}, function(data){
            $('#search-result').html(data);
        });
    });

    $('#search-input').keyup(function(){ $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);});
    $('#search-input').blur(function(){$('#search-result').fadeOut(400);});   

    $('#search-input').click(function(){$('#search-result').fadeIn(400);});

    $('#search-input').mouseenter(function(){ $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);});
    $('#search-input').mouseleave(function(){ $('#search-result').fadeOut(400)});

    $('#search-result').mouseenter(function(){ $('#search-result').stop();});
    $('#search-result').mouseleave(function(){ $('#search-result').stop();}); 

});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" size="50" id="search-input" value = '';" />
<div id="search-result"></div><!--end of search-result-->
```

Comment: In your html: `value = '';" ` ???

Comment: what does value = ''; has to do with blur effect, i have put it so that there will be no initial value in search box.

Comment: It is malformed HTML, just an FYI really.

Comment: yes but i will come to that later. do you have any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#search-input').on('blur', function() {
    $('#search-result').fadeOut(400);
});
$('#search-input').on('mouseleave', function() {

    // on mouse leave check that input
    // is focused or not
    // if not focused the fadeOut

    if( !$(this).is(':focus')) {
        $('#search-result').fadeOut(400);
    }
});
$('#search-input').on('focus mouseenter', function() {
    $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U8WaH/27/)**

#### According to comment

```
$('#search-input').on('focus mouseenter', function() {
    $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id != 'search-input' && e.target.id != 'search-result') {
        $('#search-result').fadeOut(400);
    }
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U8WaH/33/)**

Comment: it is showing effect for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` only result doesent stays open. i want results to stays open until clicked anywhere on page to close.

Comment: in you demo result stays open only when clicked in input field, i want it to stay open on mouseleave also.

Comment: @TallboY then why you need `mouseleave`

Comment: for the event if user is hovering over only input field, if hover over result field mouseleave should stop and result should stay open, hope you understand.

Comment: yes it is working, except if i click on result field it disappears.

Comment: your demo is working fine, but i don't know why here its still disappering on `onmouseclick`.

Comment: @TallboY it should disappear if you click anywhere else except input and result div

Comment: that is correct but its still disappering when clicking in result div, in your demo its not.

Answer (score 3):

Why have you bind so many events to #search-result??

Check below code if it helps you.

```
<script language="javascript" >
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#search-input').keyup(function(){
         var keyword=$(this).val();
         $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);
         //$('#search-result').html('ajax result data');
         $.get('../search/instant-search.php', {keyword: keyword}, function(data){
            $('#search-result').html(data);
             });
         }); 
        $('#search-input').bind('blur', function() {
          $('#search-result').fadeOut(400);
        });
        $('#search-input').bind('focus', function() {
          $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't help as i want the results to appear and diasapper on mouse enter and mouse leave on input field, and if i use `$('#search-input').mouseenter(function(e){ $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);});` then again same thing

Comment: updated code.. You can bind as many event as you  want, i.e. .bind('focus click',

Comment: focus is not working, again same problem with `$('#search-input').bind('mouseenter', function() {
          $('#search-result').fadeIn(400);
`